# Do Android devices use different amounts of heap and footprint for the same app

Tags: android, memory-management, heap-memory, allocation

We have developed NDK prototypes for a simple project. The code is compiled and working on device and in simulator. However when looking in the settings menu on the phones: (Samsung Galaxy Nexus(Android 4.2.2), Samsung Gio(Android 2.3.6)), running the app on the Gio takes a lot more space than when the app is run on the Galaxy Nexus. Also, the following command reports much higher heap allocations for the GIO:

```
System.out.println(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1049L);
```

We are using a static library for a lot of the functionality.
The exact results are:

**NEXUS:**

- Footprint (MB) (Java implementation)1.24
- Footprint (MB) (C++ lib implementation)0.96
- Memory allocation (MB)(Java implementation) 1.6
- Memory allocation (MB)(C++ lib implementation)  1.5

**GIO:**

- Footprint (MB) (Java implementation)1.19
- Footprint (MB) (C++ lib implementation)1.71
- Memory allocation (MB)(Java implementation) 4.6
- Memory allocation (MB)(C++ lib implementation)  5.5

What is the reason for this difference in Footprint and memory usage?

(Measuring the allocations on an iOS device (C++ lib) yields approximately the same result on a 3GS as on a Galaxy Nexus).

Comment: Does the 2 devices use the same Android OS version? I think it is related.

Comment: Updated question with android version

Comment: Android OS v2 & v4 treat memory in a different way, as they use different kernel. Maybe this is the reason of difference.

Comment: there is no point in profiling and comparing 2 different OS, leave this set of "skills" to the marketing department .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of differences between Android 2.x and Android 4.
An example is how bitmap memory is managed:

> On Android Android 2.2 (API level 8) and lower, when garbage
> collection occurs, your app's threads get stopped. This causes a lag
> that can degrade performance. **Android 2.3 adds concurrent garbage
> collection, which means that the memory is reclaimed soon after a
> bitmap is no longer referenced.**
>
> On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and
> lower, the backing pixel data for a bitmap is stored in native memory.
> It is separate from the bitmap itself, which is stored in the Dalvik
> heap. The pixel data in native memory is not released in a predictable
> manner, potentially causing an application to briefly exceed its
> memory limits and crash. **As of Android 3.0 (API Level 11), the pixel
> data is stored on the Dalvik heap along with the associated bitmap.**

Quoted from:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html